# Blazor Server App SignalR ChatHub Dependency Injection to a C# Class

Tags: c#, blazor, signalr

I am writing a Blazor Web Site, that uses a TCP/IP connection to a network attached device. The TCP/IP interface was developed using the NuGet Package: SuperSimpleTCP and works well. The Website is a single page that displays the data retrieved via the TCP/IP integration. I need to update the page when the TCP/IP Integration C# Class is updated from the device. I am attempting to use SignalR to alert the Razor Page when the TCP/IP data has changed.

In the Blazor Server Sample App, I have updated the demonstration class: WeatherServiceForecast.cs with Dependency Injection for the NavigationManager. Below is a code snippet:

```
public class WeatherForecastService
    {

        [Inject]
        NavigationManager? _navManager { get; set; }
        private HubConnection? hubConnection;
        public WeatherForecastService()
        {
            StartNav();
        }

        public async void StartNav()
        {
            hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                      .WithUrl(_navManager.ToAbsoluteUri("/chathub"))
            .Build();

            await hubConnection.StartAsync();

        }
```

In Program.cs, I am attempting to instantiate the class WeatherForcastService by adding the services to the Container:

```
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>(); 
var _weatherForecast = config.Get<WeatherForecastService>();
//WeatherForecastService instantiated here, but NavigationManager is still null.


var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chathub"); //NavManager is instantiated here, but WeatherServiceForecast is already instantiated.
//I need to get the _navigationManager here!
var _navigationManager = config.Get<NavigationManager>(); //Unfortunately, this throws an abstract type error!
//If I had the value of _navigationManager I can then set _navManager in WeatherServiceForecast:
_weatherForecastService.NavigationManager(_navigationManager);
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
```

In the code above I am creating the instance of NavigationManager, when the line:

```
app.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chathub");
```

is executed.

In the code behind of my Razor Page, I have an injection Constructor for the NavigationManager:

```
using BlazorApp8.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client;

namespace BlazorApp8.Pages
{
    public partial class FetchData
    {
        private WeatherForecast[]? forecasts;
        int foo;

        NavigationManager? _navManager { get; set; }
        private HubConnection? hubConnection;
        protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
            forecasts = await ForecastService.GetForecastAsync(DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now));
            StartNav();
        }

        public async void StartNav()
        {
            hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                      .WithUrl(_navManager.ToAbsoluteUri("/chathub"))
            .Build();

            await hubConnection.StartAsync();

        }
    }
}
```

But, when I use the same code in WeatherServiceForecast, the _navManager object is null. I believe that this is happening because the WeatherServiceForecast is instantiated before the HubChat is created and so the NavigationManager is still null.

Is there a way to retrieve the NavigationManager in Program.cs, then I can set it myself in my WeatherServiceForecast class? (Actually in my real TCP/IP interface class). Alternatively, is there a way to wait to create the WeatherServiceForecast instance until after HubChat has been instantiated?

Comment: Inject `NavManager` as a constructor parameter in `WeatherForecastService`. I think the `InjectAttribute` is intended for Razor components only.

Comment: Hello Ray, Thank you, perhaps I'm asking the wrong question. I've updated the code examples in my question. What I really need to know is how to get the object "NavManager", after the line "app.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chathub"); " is executed, in Program.cs. With that value available, I can call a method in my WeatherServiceForecast cast (Actually, TCP/IP interface class) and include the reference to the NavManager in the instance of that class.

Comment: That's not how you use dependency injection. `NavigationManager` is added to your service collection by the Blazor library, and if you want a reference to it in your `WeatherServiceForecast`, you include it as a parameter in the `WeatherServiceForecast()` constructor. Once an instance of `WeatherServiceForecast` is to be resolved, those parameters are filled in by DI, and there you have your `NavigationManager` instance. However, since `NavigationManager` is scoped, you won't be able to do this as long as `WeatherServiceForecast` is registered as a singleton, something you have to fix first.